# Is there a way to make one process dependent on another in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to make one process dependent on another in Windows?

I ask this as we have an application that needs to run a client's .exe in order to communicate via COM.  For various reasons our application will terminate unexpectedly and we need to make sure the client's .exe also terminates.

Since we have control of HOW the client .exe is launch is there a way to make this process "dependent" so that terminating our process by any means also terminates the dependent process?

Comment: There is no capability to auto-terminate the process this way. You can however make a third process that observes the mentioned two and kills #2 as soon as it sees #1 gone.

Comment: Use a job. See [`CreateJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Configure `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` in `LimitFlags`  of `JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation` via `QueryInformationJobObject` and `SetInformationJobObject`. Add the client process handle using `AssignProcessToJobObject`.

Comment: Normally the system manages the lifetime of COM servers automatically.

Comment: If you can't trust your EXE to terminate in a controlled way then create another EXE that you can trust. A simple one, focus on simple, a guard process that doesn't do anything but pay attention to the processes terminating. And uses TerminateProcess() when necessary. Such a guard process will come in handy to solve your real problem as well. It can call MiniDumpCreateDump().

Comment: If you can put a simple heartbeat interface into your server, the client can call it occasionally and kill itself when the response errors out.

Comment: @Hans: The particular DbgHelp function is [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx).